# Django login username label not being overwritten

Tags: django, forms

I added email to be used as an alternative input for the default Django login form and wish to change the label to Username/Email but the common solution I find isn't working.

I tried variations on the following and some other solutions with no change to the default Username label.

1. Create a custom login form extending the normal one.

   ```py
   class CustomLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
       username = forms.CharField(
           label="Your Custom Label",
           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True})
       )
   ```
2. Configure a view to use the custom form with the custom login template.

   ```py
   # views.py
   from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
   from .forms import CustomAuthenticationForm

   class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
       authentication_form = CustomAuthenticationForm
       template_name = 'login.html'
   ```
3. Configure the url.

   ```py
   # urls.py
   from django.urls import path
   from .views import CustomLoginView

   urlpatterns = [
       path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
       # other URL patterns
   ]
   ```

I'm using crispy forms if that matters so in my template I'm using `{{ form|crispy }}`.

I simply want to change the label but am usually getting doubled up labels with common solutions if I include another `{{ form.username|as_crispy_field }}` in addition to a label tag. Can I remove the label from this latter implementation somehow as a potential solution?

I also tried:

```py
class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Username/Email'
```